# Html :visited selector not working when using target="_blank" in IE11

Tags: html, css

In html link not change color for visited link when target attribute set "_blank" on IE11.

> css

```
#lnk:visited
{
   color: red;
}
```

> html

```
 <a id="lnk" href="some url" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

After click "a" changes color to red, but when refresh the page "a" not changes color to red on IE11.

Comment: Selector :visited working when target is not set to blank otherwise not working on IE11. Please read my question more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tag selector instead

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6d3IM0?p=preview

```
<style>
a:visited {
  color: red;
}
</style>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

Comment: Its not working, I changed the color to green and it still showing the basic blue color.

Comment: Please check plunker above.

Answer (score 0):

1.First way you can add the same if you want all the link to act same regarding color.

```
  a:visited {
  color: red;
}
```

2.second way only specific to your link ID

```
   a#lnk:visited {
  color: red;
}
```

3. Also you can use "vlink Attribute" from HTML to specify the color of visited links in a document.

Comment: vlink attribute is not supported in HTML5

Comment: Yes .. It is not supported. That's why I kept the same in 3rd option. Only in case someone using an older version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
a#lnk:visited {
  color: red;
}
</style>
<a id="lnk" href="some url" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on onclick event

```css
.visited
{
   color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<a class="" id="lnk" href="some url" target="test.php" onclick="this.className='visited' ">click me</a>
```

`Run code snippet` and click `Hide results` and then run .